# can we create static member in react?

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, ecma

in java we have static members which is same copy for all the instances, is there any ways to active same in react ,

i already solved the problem using **redux**., but i eagerly searching to solve the problem by using ***static members***

in java

```
public class Cart {

    static int totalItemInCart = 0; 
}


class Order{

    static boolean pushToCart() {

        Cart.totalItemInCart += Cart.totalItemInCart+1;     
        return true;
    }
}

class CancelOrder{  

    static boolean removeFromCart() {

        Cart.totalItemInCart += Cart.totalItemInCart-1;     
        return true;
    }
}

class User {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Order.pushToCart(); // item added to cart
        Order.pushToCart(); // item added to cart
        CancelOrder.removeFromCart(); // one item removed from cart 

        // if print the count we will get totalItemInCart is 2 
        System.out.println("number of items in cart" + Cart.totalItemInCart);
    }

}
```

now i want do the same in react, is there any way we can access a class member in multiple instances.

in react as of now i only can access *initial values*

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return <h1>Count : {new Count().state.count} </h1>;
  }
}

class Count extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
      count:0
    }
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

output will be

> Count : {new Count().state.count}

Comment: i already solved the problem using redux., but i eagerly searching to solve the problem by using static members

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript (which react is based) is not a truly OOP like Java, it's a [prototype type based language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming), So there is not a straight equivalent for class and static variables.

In react for those global stuff we would use Redux for data or React.Context api for application global state.

However with ES6 you can write class like syntax like these

```
class Cart {
  static count = 0;

  add = () => {
    Cart.count++;
  };
  remove = () => {
    Cart.count--;
  };

  print = () => {
    console.log(Cart.count);
  };
}
```

which work pretty much like Java's class variables. you can try this example, notice on render, the value still the same one. https://codesandbox.io/s/wo62022jo5

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to assign a variable to the class so that each instance of the class will include the variable. This value wouldn't be completely static as it could be reassigned via `this.variableName = 'newValue'`.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    variableName = 'value'

    render() {
      return <div>{this.variableName}</div>
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could make it a  method that returns a constant, in this case `value` could no longer be overwritten.

```
const value = 'value'
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    getValue() {
      return value
    }

    render() {
      return <div>{this.variableName}</div>
    }
}
```

Furthermore, suppose the static value could change and you wanted all components to be able to read the updated value (without redux) then you could wrap it in an object.

Alternatively you could make it a  method that returns a constant, in this case `value` could no longer be overwritten.

```
const staticProperty = {
  value: 'value'
}
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    getValue() {
      return staticProperty.value
    }

    render() {
      return <div>{this.variableName}</div>
    }
}
```

In the above example, since `staticValue` is mutable you could run `staticValue.value = 'some new value'` and it would update the value. The next time any component calls `this.getvalue()` they would get `my new value`. The problem with this approach is that mutating the `staticValue.value` would not trigger components to update, since no prop or state changes occurred.

If you would like components to receive updates on property changes, well at that point you are re-implementing Redux and I would recommend you use Redux. You would need to subscribe each component to track the changes to a certain section of the state, and you can see how to accomplish that by looking at the Redux source code: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/createStore.js

Comment: thanks for input, but how can we reinitialise the value

Comment: I just added that as the third example! @SunilKumar

Comment: thank you Alexei sir., i got it but is there any way to  trigger components to update

Comment: No problem, in order to make components update you would need to set up either `eventListeners` or `subscribers` to track whether the property value has changed. But that is exactly what `redux` does. Redux's `selector` listens to changes on a property and tells the component to update. If you're going to this distance to share a property then I would highly recommend you use `Redux` instead of recreating it by hand using shared static properties and event listeners.

Comment: sir could you please review my code  https://codesandbox.io/s/wnxp7rzvjw

Comment: @SunilKumar I've looked at your code and can see a few areas for improvement. Here is a working copy of what you want: https://codesandbox.io/s/2ol27k3z4r

In general you want to avoid calling `render()`. That function should be automatically called when a component's state changes, thus I refactored the increment and decrement to use `this.setState()`. Each cart has it's own instance of `count` and by using `this.setState()` it automatically triggers a render(). Also the `onPlus` and `onMinus` are defined in the cart, that way they utilize `this.setState()` and will also update the parent.

Answer (score 0):

please go through with link https://codesandbox.io/s/wnxp7rzvjw, i got the solution

i used one parent class to create a common instance for both the class

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      countInstance: new Cart(this)
    };
  }

  onPlus = () => {
    this.state.countInstance.state.count += 1;
    this.state.countInstance.render();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Increment countInstance={this.state.countInstance} />
        <Decrement countInstance={this.state.countInstance} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Increment extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  onPlus = () => {
    this.props.countInstance.state.count += 1;
    this.props.countInstance.render();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Count in first componet: {this.props.countInstance.state.count}</h1>
        <button onClick={this.onPlus}>+</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Decrement extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  onMinus = () => {
    this.props.countInstance.state.count -= 1;
    this.props.countInstance.render();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>
          Count in second componet : {this.props.countInstance.state.count}
        </h1>
        <button onClick={this.onMinus}>-</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Cart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    };
  }

  updateParent = () => {
    this.props.setState({
      update: !this.state.update
    });
  };
  render() {
    {
      this.updateParent();
    }
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```